# Canvas circle border is cutting - Android

Tags: android, canvas

I'm using canvas to draw a circle and border. The circle fill color and border color are different. I'm also drawing a text in the center of the circle. But the problem I'm facing is that the edges on all four sides of the circle seems to be cut off.

[image: This is the result of below mentioned code]

This is the code I'm using for drawing the circle, border and text.

```
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas)
    try {
        /** Draw Circle **/
        drawPaint.color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white_static)
        drawPaint.style = Paint.Style.FILL
        canvas.drawCircle(size, size, size, drawPaint)

        /** Draw Border **/
        borderPaint.color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.color_primary)
        borderPaint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        borderPaint.strokeJoin = Paint.Join.ROUND
        borderPaint.strokeWidth = 2f
        canvas.drawCircle(size, size, size, borderPaint)

        /** Draw Text **/
        textPaint.textAlign = Paint.Align.CENTER
        textPaint.color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.color_primary)
        val xPos = width / 2
        val yPos = (height / 2 - (textPaint.descent() + textPaint.ascent()) / 2).toInt()
        
        /** Add Text **/
        canvas.drawText(text!!, xPos.toFloat(), yPos.toFloat(), textPaint)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        println("CircularTextView => Exception caught => $e")
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to override onMeasure and add extra pixels to view dimensions.. or during onDraw, you discount some pixels from "size". THIs issue is happening because you are exceeding the area calculated during onMeasure. You need to consider the stroke width while calculating the view size

Comment: There's no actual question, but it's clear what the author wants to ask